# Existence of a unique minimizer of a given functional

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, convex-analysis, functional-equations

> Let $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ for $\Omega$ an open bounded set of $\mathbb{R}^N$. We consider $$ J(u) := \int_{\Omega} \left( \left| \nabla_x u(x) \right|^2 - f(x) \cdot u(x) \right) {\rm d} x $$ Prove that there exists a unique minimizer.

---

**My attempt**: By using the definition, I can check this functional is convex. That means if i can prove that this functional exists a minimizer, then it will be unique. But i don't know how to prove that. Can you help me to solve this problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware of Lax Milgram theorem ?

Comment: Yes i knew this theorem but this is the first time i had approached this problem? Can you help me to solve it?

Comment: Then link this energy function to a weak formulation problem

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$J(u) = \frac{1}{2}a(u,u) - L(u)$$
Where $$a(u,v) = 2 \int_\Omega \nabla u(x) \nabla v(x) dx$$
and
$$ L(u) = \int_\Omega f(x)dx $$
We can verify these functions fullfill all the Lax-Milgram hypotheses. Then by Lax-Milgram theorem there exists a unique $v$ such that $ \forall u, a(u,v)=L(u)$. We show that this $v$ is the also the minimizer of $v$ :

Let $w$ be an arbitrary function, then
\begin{align}
J(v+w) &= J(v) + ( a(v,w)-L(w) ) + \frac{1}{2} a(w,w) \\
&= J(v)  + \frac{1}{2} a(w,w) \\
&\geq J(v) +  \frac{\alpha}{2} \|w\|^2 \text{ since $a(.|.)$ is coercive}\\
\end{align}

Therefore $\forall w, J(v) \leq J(w)$ and $v$ is unique.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: @Pipnap Welcome to M.S.E.  If this answered your question, go ahead and check the little check box to accept the answer.  That both marks the question as one that's been answered and awards a bit of rep.

Comment: I want to have a chance to practice more with this type of exercise. Can you suggest me some books, which contains this kind of exercise?